# How do i set one second delay between iterations?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];


function out(ar){

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    for (var i=0; i<ar.length;i++){

      for (var j=0;j<ar[i].length;j++){

        document.write(ar[i][j]);

      }
    document.write("</br>");
    }
  clearInterval(interval);
  },1000);

}

out(arr);
```

http://jsbin.com/edanib/edit

This code works, but i would like to make one second delay before outputting every number.
The above code cannot do that. How do i do that in **vanilla** Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` isn't guaranteed to get you 1 second spacing because other things might run, but you can get close with the following

```
function out(ar) {
  var i = 0, j = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    // Start with the next row if the last one was finished.
    if (i < ar.length && j == ar[i].length) {
      ++i; 
      j = 0;
      // Put a line after it.
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
    // Check if we're out of rows.
    if (i >= ar.length) { clearInterval(interval); return; }

    // Write out a number.
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('' + ar[i][j]));

    // We're done with the cell that we just wrote.
    ++j;
  }, 1000 /* milliseconds */);
}
```

Put the array indices outside the function, so each time the interval fires, it gets the loop state from the last run.

Also, you can't use `document.write` inside an interval handler because calling `document.write` after the document has closed clobbers the existing document.

Comment: thanks! but i would like to output them like this 123 br 456 br 789  Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a loop with `setInterval`.  Have the function capture the counters and increment them appropriate at every turn

Try the following

```
function output(arr) {
  var i = 0; 
  var j = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function () { 

    while (i < arr.length && j === arr[i].length) {
      j = 0;
      i++;
    }

    if (i === arr.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      document.write(arr[i][j]);
    }
    j++;
  }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Minor nit.  This will cause exception spam in the console if passed an empty array.

Comment: @MikeSamuel good catch.  Updated to handle empty `arr` and properly handle empty sub arrays (`arr[i]`)

Answer (score 0):

try it like this: first, create a single-dimension array, which you give to an output function that calls itself delayed:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];


function out(ar){
    var singleDim = []
    for (var i=0; i<ar.length;i++){

      for (var j=0;j<ar[i].length;j++){

          singleDim.push(ar[i][j]);

      }
    }
    outDelayed(singleDim,0,1000);
}

function outDelayed(arr,index,delay) {
    if (index < arr.length) {
        document.write(arr[index]);
        setTimeout(function(){
            outDelay(arr,index+1,delay);
        },delay);
    }
}

out(arr);
```